# Syncing EXIF's between photos

Tags: exif

I have alot of photos that had their dates wiped during a move. I do have a backup of the photo's with correct EXIF (modified dates...or creation dates...whatever android uses to sort photos). Is there software that will bulk compare files from 2 different folders and transfer EXIF data from one to the other for the same files with different EXIF data?

Answer (score 1):

**`jhead`** can do that:

```
jhead -te <file_with_exif> <targetFile>
```

or, as the manpage has it for your batch job, provided file names are identical:

```
jhead -te "originals/&i" *.jpg
```

On a Linux machine, you'd just need to install the package going by the same name (`jhead`)

Comment: Is this a command line program like exiftool or does it have a gui?

Comment: Command-line, as the examples show – and no GUI included (and I'm not aware of any, sorry). You can find [the source here](https://github.com/Matthias-Wandel/jhead).